# Converting long/lat to pixel x/y, given a zoom-level

Tags: .net, google-maps, maps, coordinates, pixel

I'm trying to develop a page in ASP.NET that will act as a tile-server for a Google Map

It will pull a collection of latitude/longitude points from the database, then render them as small red dots on a transparent background, given a zoom-level (default: 15).

It will then return the result as a GIF-type image.

Have any algorithms or libraries been developed that allow me to take this set of latitudes/longitudes and convert them to a set of 2D pixel co-ordinates, given a zoom level?

(This is all being done server-side, so I can't use the Google Maps API.)

---

Update: Found a code-sample in Perl that does something similar:

http://blog.barros.ws/2009/03/06/convert-lat-lng-and-zoom-values-to-pixel-xy-on-a-map/

Trouble is, I don't know Perl, and don't really have the time to crack open a book and learn it.

Can anyone help me to decipher what's going on in this function?

```
sub Google_Coord_to_Pix
{
    my $value   = shift ;
    my $lat = shift ;
    my $lng = shift ;
    my @d       = ( ) ; 
    my $e       = 0 ;

    $d[1] = sprintf("%0.0f", $$value{'bmO'} + $lng * $$value{'pixLngDeg'} ) ;

    $e = sin($lat * $$value{'Wa'}) ;

    if( $e > 0.99999 )
    {
        $e = 0.99999 ;
    }

    if( $e < -0.99999 )
    {
        $e = -0.99999 ;
    }

    $d[0] = sprintf("%0.0f", $$value{'bmO'} + 0.5 * log((1 + $e) / (1 - $e)) * (-1) * $$value{'pixLngRad'} ) ;

    return (@d) ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If it is a Mercator projection, you shouldn't need to worry about the curvature of the earth since all of the lat/lon lines are at equal spacing"

Perhaps you're thinking of the Geographic (aka Plate Carree) projection? The Mercator projection does have equally spaced lines of longitude, but does *not* have equally spaced lines of latitude (lat = atan(sinh(y)), so 90° is at infinity).

BTW, the math for the Mercator projection on a sphere is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Mathematics_of_the_projection), but if Google Maps is using the WGS84 ellipsoid and you need to get it exact it gets more complicated. In that case, I'd look at [this](http://pubs.er.usgs.gov/usgspubs/pp/pp1395), but beware: it's not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 11):

Here's some code I'm currently using.  It's in PHP.

```
// Returns longitude in pixels at a certain zoom level
function lonToX($lon, $zoom) {
    $offset = 256 << ($zoom-1);
    return round($offset + ($offset * $lon / 180));
}
// Returns latitude in pixels at a certain zoom level
function latToY($lat, $zoom) {
    $offset = 256 << ($zoom-1);
    return round($offset - $offset/pi() * log((1 + sin($lat * pi() / 180)) / (1 - sin($lat * pi() / 180))) / 2);
}
```

Based on code from [this page](http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/11/introduction-to-marker-clustering-with-google-maps), written by [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24433/mika-tuupola).

Good luck!

**Update:** [This map](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/) is a great way to help understand how tiles work in Google Maps

**Edit:** Here's an equivalent set of functions in VB.NET:

```
Public Function LonToX(Lon As Double, Zoom as UInteger) As UInteger
    Dim Offset = 256 << (Zoom - 1)
    Return Math.Round(Offset + (Offset * Lon / 180))
End Function

Public Function LatToY(Lat As Double, Zoom as UInteger) As UInteger
    Dim Offset = 256 << (Zoom - 1)
    Return Math.Round(Offset - Offset / Math.Pi * Math.Log((1 + Math.Sin(Lat * Math.Pi / 180)) / (1 - Math.Sin(Lat * Math.Pi / 180))) / 2)
End Function
```

And in C#:

```
public uint lonToX(double lon, uint zoom) {
    uint offset = 256 << (zoom - 1);
    return Math.Round(offset + (offset * lon / 180));
}

public uint latToY(double lat, uint zoom) {
    uint offset = 256 << (zoom - 1);
    return Math.Round(offset - offset / Math.Pi * Math.Log((1 + Math.Sin(lat * Math.Pi / 180)) / (1 - Math.Sin(lat * Math.Pi / 180))) / 2);
}
```

Comment: +½ -- although the original question was for a .NET solution, this is an excellent and easy-to-implement solution, and it should be trivial for the reader to convert this into C# or VB.NET.