# How to download Google Maps to use it offline on Android application

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, offline

Basically, what I want to do is something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Tqr.jpg)

I read some solutions about using another maps, but I have all my project build it on Google Maps, so I was looking for something to adapt it to that.

I want to download an area of the map (as map or as image) with markers that are in a local database, and after load it offline with their respective markers.

I hope someone can help me, is the last part of my project.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46538148/6950238) question and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46569769/6950238) answer

Comment: I read that before, but I dont know how to build the selection area of the map for the users like in the image, with the information about tiles that are in there @AndriiOmelchenko

Comment: Just convert lat/lon to tiles coords like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1602577/6950238) answer.

Comment: Yeah I know how to do that, but no idea how to implement the selection square to select an map area with zoom also @AndriiOmelchenko

Comment: Just add view over view with map and do with it what you want (draw rectangles, change transparency, etc.). Or you can override `onDraw()` method for map view.